# Проблема с жестким диском

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hdd

Проблема в следующем: в процессе работы система постоянно немного подвисает, при этом индикатор обращения к hdd горит постоянно. Запустил программу SMART Data % Self-Tests, но не могу понять с диском все хорошо или нет.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вывод команды  smartctl -a /dev/sda : 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Еще бы сырые данные для ошибок... Но есть подозрение что посыпался.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Подскажите, пожалуйста, как отобразить/получить сырые данные и я прикреплю их к вопросу.

Comment: smartctl -a /dev/sda к примеру. Там будет такая же таблица, но справа должна быть еще колонка raw value или как-то так.

Comment: А, у вас и в этом окне 9 с лишним миллионов бэд-секторов. В помойку диск.

Comment: Хотя, может и проблемы с кабелем. Но в любом случае, я бы на нем ничего ценного не хранил.

Comment: badblocks или mhdd на выбор. Пощупайте.

Comment: да вот тут говорили о питании, была хохмочка что просто блок питания не тянул. Один из 4-х винтов дурака валял

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, в каком месте 9м бэдов? Rellocated_sector_count говорит о 143.

Comment: @ВадимНиколаев, maint про mhdd правильно подсказал. Только не забудь перевести режим контроллера винта в IDE режим. Ну и начинай копить бабки на новый. Этому долго жить вряд ли удастся.

Comment: @donRumata на первом скрине в заголовке окна